# Assistance in error determination using Scipy.Minimize (with MVE) using OLS

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

Let's say you are given a dataset

```
data=[array([0.01252837, 0.00994032, 0.02607758, 0.02938639, 0.03470389,
       0.0393117 , 0.05045751, 0.05288866]), array([0.01096586, 0.0093723 , 0.02996665, 0.0490254 , 0.06359686,
       0.07470107, 0.07533133, 0.10770218]), array([0.0108    , 0.01922004, 0.0290243 , 0.03236109, 0.00761577,
       0.05216742, 0.05526853, 0.06572701]), array([0.01744162, 0.02563377, 0.03473111, 0.04372516, 0.05533209,
       0.06429533, 0.06852919, 0.08112336]), array([0.01664812, 0.03377632, 0.04334155, 0.05260618, 0.06893069,
       0.07831481, 0.08656102, 0.0999732 ]), array([0.01933805, 0.02861486, 0.04197618, 0.05017609, 0.06353904,
       0.07471151, 0.08393098, 0.09447883])]
```

And you are trying to globally fit it to data using a model

```
model=wmax*((p+l+k-np.sqrt(((p+l+k)**2)-(4*p*l)))/(2*p)) #where wmax and k are adjustable parameters
#given p and l
p=(array([0.28, 0.26, 0.25, 0.23, 0.21, 0.19, 0.18, 0.15])
l=array([0.14, 0.26, 0.37, 0.47, 0.63, 0.77, 0.88, 1.1 ])
```

So setting this all up in the code

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from statsmodels.tools.numdiff import approx_hess2
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

def global_fun(par,p,l,data):   
    k,wmax=par
    chi2=0
    for d in data:
        model=wmax*((p+l+k-np.sqrt(((p+l+k)**2)-(4*p*l)))/(2*p))
        chi2+=np.sum((d-model)**2)
    return chi2 

solution=minimize(global_fun,args=(p,l,data),x0=[1,0.01],bounds=((0,np.inf),)*2)
```

Now there are 2 ways to calculate errors. One is use the hessian calculated from L-BFGS, as such

```
np.sqrt(np.diag((solution.hess_inv).todense()))
```

Although I have heard it's best to not use the calculated Hessian in L-BFGS. So you can instead do

```
error=approx_hess2(solution.x,global_fun,args=(p,l,data))
np.sqrt(np.diag(inv(error))))
```

Doing such for this data set gives you these results

```
Solution = [3.19959051 0.33526739] 
Error from L-BGFS Hessian= [85.14702579  8.87746697]
Error from approx_hess2= [156.72145858  12.74617055]
```

The issue is dual fold:

1. There is quite a difference between L-BGFS and approx_hess2.
2. The error is very large, despite a good fit (fun=8e-3)

But more importantly, using the same dataset and fitting it in Matlab using nlinfit gives much lower errors.

Why is the error for this so high? Is there a better way to calculate errors when it comes to OLS? Have I set this up incorrectly? Is there another method to calculate errors for OLS outside of the covariance matrix to help confirm I'm getting the right results?

Any help would greatly be appreciated!